# Polling timer function in C

Tags: optimization, c

I've implemented a polling function with a timer in C, that every 10s checks a given condition (I've just replaced it for a log to stdout for testing purposes only) but I would like to know your opinion on this code, namely if there is a simpler way to achieve the same result, what issues may arise concerning performance, thread-safety, memory footprint. I'm interested in writing the most simple, correct and fast code for this. Suggestions are, as always, welcome.

```
/* includes removed for clarity */

void signalAlarmHandler(int signum) {
  switch(signum) {
  case SIGINT:
    fprintf(stdout, "received interrupt. going to exit.\n");
    exit(0);
    break;
  case SIGALRM:
    fprintf(stdout, "received signal alarm.\n");
    /* checking for condition here */
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if(initializeEnvironment(argc, argv) == -1) {
    return -1;
  }
  else {

    signal(SIGINT, signalAlarmHandler); /* for testing purposes */
    signal(SIGALRM, signalAlarmHandler);

    fprintf(stdout, "starting the signal alarm stuff\n");
    while(1) {
      alarm(10);
      sleep(20);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which system is this for? C has no function called sleep() and my answer would be quite different if this was intended for Windows or Linux or something else.

Comment: @Lundin: sleep() is part of the Posix standard (and thus in nearly every C-stdlib) so it is implemented in every C-stdlib implemented on OS that conform to the Posix standard.

Comment: @Tux There are plenty of functions called sleep() in all kinds of systems. Since there are no includes in the code posted, nor any tags, we can't really make any assumptions.

Comment: I've ommited the includes, but if you want to know it's for a Linux system and these are the includes:
`code`
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
`code`

Answer (score 1):

What is a reason for using alarm() with sleep()? Why not just

```
void sigIntHandler(int signum) {
  fprintf(stdout, "received interrupt. going to exit.\n");
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if(initializeEnvironment(argc, argv) == -1) {
    return -1;
  }
  signal(SIGINT, signalAlarmHandler); /* for testing purposes */

  while(1) {
    sleep(10);
    /* checking for condition here */
  }
}
```

Also:

- fprintf() is not signal-safe, better not to use it from signal handler
- signal() is obsolete and implementation-dependent, use sigaction() for consistent results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to check for a given condition at every 10s, so I use alarm() to receive a SIGALRM for this purpose. Then I use sleep() for the program to do nothing but wait. When the 10s have passed, the program receives a SIGALRM and handles it, e.g., checks for a given condition. Also, can you tell me how do you know that fprintf is not signal-safe? I've read the manpage for fprintf and there is nothing there pointing for this. Also, any books, articles you can point me for reading on this topic? Regards ;)

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal - here you can find POSIX list of safe functions. By the way, your code will check for condition only once: alarm() causes single signal to be delivered. Call alarm() again in signal handler or use setitimer() for periodic signal delivery.

Comment: Thank you blaze. Are you sure my code will check only once for the condition? Because I can see that string on stdout every 10s... In the while loop I call alarm(), is this different from not calling alarm() in the while loop and calling it on the signalAlarmHandler function?